# Toshiba DX735 Touch Screen Doesn't Work

Tags: drivers, 12.04, touchscreen

I just purchased this PC, and I'm going to dual-boot it with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I know that the touchscreen doesn't work when I use a Ubuntu 11.10 Live CD (32-bit).

Is there a driver that will work on Ubuntu for this touch screen and can you please (if available) leave a link to the .deb file or something?

Comment: anyone? the stable release is in less than a week...

Comment: Can you add `lsusb` output and/or touchscreen model?

Answer (score 1):

If you use 12.04 64bit through WUBI, it should pick up the touch screen. Mine did without me having to install any drivers. However, 12.10 is a different story so I went back to 12.04. I have a ProLite Monitor.